# Origin of a phrase (v'hu yiftach libeinu)

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla

After the Kiddusha D'sidra the following [words](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Concluding_Prayers%2C_Uva_Letzion.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) appear:

הוּא יִפְתַּח לִבֵּנוּ בְּתורָתו. וְיָשֵׂם בְּלִבֵּנוּ אַהֲבָתו וְיִרְאָתו וְלַעֲשׂות רְצונו וּלְעָבְדו בְּלֵבָב שָׁלֵם.

The Beurei Hatefilah site mentions this section [as](https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-07-25_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) "The balance of the paragraph consists of [pesukim] except for the following:" and indicates that a phrase like this appears in the [works](https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-07-04Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) of R' Saadia Gaon but gives no source beyond that.

I have a personal sense of what drives this line, but I'm wondering if there are any concrete earlier sources, or discussion of the development of this sentence.

Comment: The Abudraham cryptically says about the first part that it's לשון חכמים הוא. Ri bar Yakar says the same thing

Comment: Looking at different versions of Abudraham and Ri Bar Yakar, they cite [Berachos 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.17a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Not sure  about וישם בלבנו וגו

Comment: PS: I think your links are backwards. As well, here's the location in Rav Saadia Gaon's [siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=84)